# StaticInjectorError in angular DOM

Tags: angular

When I use table element in Angular sometimes show me this error in the console of the browser
What's the problem? 
How can I solve it? 
angular HTML:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered table-condensed  ">
  <thead>
    <tr class="tr-bottom-color-orrange">

      <th class="text-center">name</th>

    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let item of listItem">

      <td class="text-left">
        {{ item.name }}
      </td>      
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

error:

```
ERROR Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[TableDirective -> ColumnResizingService]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[TableDirective -> ColumnResizingService]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for ColumnResizingService!
    at _NullInjector.get (core.js:1002)
    at resolveToken (core.js:1300)
    at tryResolveToken (core.js:1242)
    at StaticInjector.get (core.js:1110)
    at resolveToken (core.js:1300)
    at tryResolveToken (core.js:1242)
    at StaticInjector.get (core.js:1110)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js:10854)
    at NgModuleRef_.get (core.js:12087)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js:10854)
```

I'm using lazy loading module
ContractModule :

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    SharedModule,
    KendoSharedModule,
    SmartadminModule,
    SmartadminValidationModule,
    PaginationModule.forRoot(),
    DpDatePickerModule,
    NgxMaskModule.forRoot(),
    SmartadminWizardsModule,
    ContractRoutingModule,
  ],
  providers: [ContractResolverService],
  declarations: [AddContractComponent, ListContractComponent, AddWarrantyComponent]
})
export class ContractModule { }
```

Comment: @MohammandDaliri have you add `ColumnResizingService` in `AppModule` in providers

Comment: nothing wrong in the given code. You may be using some directive/service which is not provided.

Comment: @Abhishek I don't add ColumnResizingService in AppModule.What is it(ColumnResizingService )?

Comment: @SachinGupta All services define in provides the module.

Comment: @Sajeetharan I'm using lazy loading module and added to question

Comment: KendoSharedModule exports TableDirective that requires ColumnResizingService to be in DI

Comment: @MohammadDaliri can you import everything for `TableDirective`?

Comment: @Abhishek in other components of this module I use kendo grid but in this component, I don't use kendo grid. I use table HTML

Comment: You use TableDirective here because its selector is `table`

Comment: @ yurzui Is it a probelm of my code?

Comment: Try importing ColumnResizingService  from kendo and add it to providers

Comment: I try to import ColumnResizingService in providers of ContractModule but show above error again

Comment: Try adding  it to AppModule

Comment: @yurzui Thanks for the help I try but  it is doesn't work

Comment: Can you recreate this issue in github repository so I can help?

Comment: Is there a solution for this issue? I'm using Kendo grid in one component but into another component that belongs to the same module I cannot add a normal table.

Answer (score 4):

Was facing the same issue and found it was caused by importing the 'SharedModule' from Kendo.

Comment: You are right. I was also importing some unneeded modules like the SharedModule.

Comment: Any idea how this can be solved without removing SharedModule?

Comment: You shouldn't need to import the kendo SharedModule, only the kendo component module that you are trying to use

Answer (score 1):

Add `ColumnResizingService` in `AppModule` providers.